# select elements from two unequal length numpy arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy

consider two numpy arrays

```
array1 = np.arange(0,6)
array2 = np.arange(0,12)
```

i want to a run a loop (preferably a list comprehension) where the desire output for a single round is

```
print(array1[0])
print(array2[0],array2[1]) or

print(array1[1])
print(array2[2], array2[3])
```

ie the loop runs six times, but for every round in array1 it selects the two consecutive elements from array2.

I have tried something like

```
for i in xrange(array1):
    for v in xrange(array2):
```

but this evidently runs the second loop inside the first one, How can i run them simultaneously but select different number of elements from each array in one round?

I have also tried making the loops equal in length such as

```
 array1 = np.repeat(np.arange(0,6),2).ravel()
 array1 = [0,0,1,1,2,2.....5,5]
```

however, this will make the length of the two arrays equal but i still cannot get the desired output

(In actual case, the elements of the array are pandas Series objects)

Comment: Reshape second array : `array2.reshape(-1,2)` and then use the same iterating index to index into `array1` and reshaped `array2`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with pandas. Removed tag.

Comment: @Divakar. Thanks for reminding me of the `-1` shape. I will incorporate it into my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in xrange(array1):
   print(array1[i])
   print(array2[2*i],array2[2*i+1])
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of different ways of going about this. One thing you can do is use the indices:

```
for ind, item in array1:
    print(item, array2[2*ind:2*ind+2])
```

This does not use the full power of numpy, however. The easiest thing I can think of is to concatenate your arrays into a single array containing the desired sequence. You can make it into a 2D array for easy iteration, where each column or row will be the sequence of three elements you want:

```
array1 = np.arange(6)
array2 = np.arange(12)
combo = np.concatenate((array1.reshape(-1, 1), array2.reshape(-1, 2)), axis=1)
for row in combo:
    print(row)
```

Results in

```
[0 0 1]
[1 2 3]
[2 4 5]
[3 6 7]
[4 8 9]
[ 5 10 11]
```

In this case, the explicit reshape of `array1` is necessary because `array1.T` will result in a 1D array.

You can use a hybrid of the two approaches, as @Divakar suggests, where you reshape `a2` but iterate using the index:

```
array3 = array2.reshape(-1, 2)
for ind, item in array1:
    print(item, array3[ind])
```

Comment: And additional benefit of no extra memory requirements with that `reshape`.

Comment: @Divakar Is it because it returns a 'view of the array' if possible?

Comment: @kmario23 That's right! Do : `array2.reshape(-1,2)[2] = 99` and you would changed `array2` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as @MadPhysicist mentioned, there are a lot of ways to do this.... but the simplest is

```
>>> for x,y,z in zip(array1,array2[:-1:2],array2[1::2]):
...  print x,y,z
... 
0 0 1
1 2 3
2 4 5
3 6 7
4 8 9
5 10 11
```

Comment: You can also do `zip(array1, *array2.reshape(-1, 2).T)`. Either way, +1 for using zip.

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist, I believe that my version (maybe less Pythonical) but more readable.

Comment: I left the comment as more as a side-note for future readers than as a note to you really. I agree that the way you wrote it is for the best. Mine would work better only if you had a much larger number of columns than 2.